# Why does Mountain Lion ask me for my password when trying to SSH even though I have setup public/private keys?

Tags: macos, ssh

On Mac OS X Mountain Lion (10.8) I have setup public/private keys for passwordless SSH to another Mountain Lion machine but when I try to SSH to the other machine it still asks for my password. I have verified permissions of the `~/.ssh` directory and the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys2` file are correct. Verbose output from `ssh -vvv my.server.com` does not show any type of failure and there is nothing indicating a failure in the `/var/log/system.log`.

My keys work fine when connecting to Linux and Mac OS X Lion (10.7) machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Mountain Lion the `sshd` configuration (`/etc/sshd_config`) was changed and `sshd` no longer looks at `~/.ssh/authorized_keys2` for valid keys.

`/etc/sshd_config` on Lion (line 46):

```
#AuthorizedKeysFile     .ssh/authorized_keys
```

`/etc/sshd_config` on Mountain Lion (line 48):

```
# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys
```

If you don’t wish to edit the `/etc/sshd_config` on the target machine you can either rename `~/.ssh/authorized_keys2` to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` or symlink it.

#### Symlink `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys2`

```
ln -s ~/.ssh/authorized_keys ~/.ssh/authorized_keys2
```

#### Rename `~/.ssh/authorized_keys2`

```
mv ~/.ssh/authorized_keys2 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```